# Separate API calls using dispatch from redux-forms "onSubmit"

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I integrated redux-form as the docs suggest and everything works fine.
As the next step i wanted to add async API-calls to my application and combine them with the forms created by `redux-form`.

As usual, i want to seperate my ui components from application logic. The redux way of doing this is dispatching actions in the components and doing the necessary logic inside the reducers. When you need async operations inside your actions/actionCreators one uses `redux-thunk` or probably other libraries like `redux-saga`.

Let's assume i want to use `redux-thunk` to use async api calls inside my actionCreators for updating my application state. The question now is, how would anyone combine this with the logic that `redux-form` gives us in the `onSubmit` function? This function assumes that you return a promise to handle the states of the form and i cannot find a way to combine this with the usual way of using actions.

Doesn't `redux-form` provide a reduxy way of handling the submit function using actions?

Feel free to ask anything if something is unclear or you need some code to get a clearer picture of what i want to achive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux-form allows you to pass in a submit handler property, which you can use elsewhere.

A possible approach.

Your **parent component**:

```
class FormHandler extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(data) {
    return this.props.asyncAction(data).then(() => {
      throw new SubmissionError({ user: 'Username already taken.', _error: 'Form submission failed' });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <MyForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { asyncAction })(FormHandler);
```

You can connect your parent component, like you would normally do without redux-form, and `handleSubmit` can be an action which is connected to your store.

*You can find more about submit validation on [Redux form official documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/submitValidation/)*.

Your **redux-form `MyForm`**:

```
class MyForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { error, handleSubmit, onSubmit, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          ... fields ...
          <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Create</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

MyForm.PropTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
})(MyForm);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the way i'm doing it right now. I'm interested in the way you would connect the `handleSubmit` function of the parent component with async submit validation (you need to return a promise in the `handleSubmit` function) with API calls bound to the redux-store using side-effects like `redux-thunk`. `redux-thunk` actionCreators need to return a function with dispatch as props.

Comment: @choise see my edit. I added a pretty much complete example of the parent, including `react-redux` connection and a reference to the official docs validation. If you don't use `react-redux`, simply dispatch the action as you would normally do, that does not change.